# Why is uncommenting this line causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

For some reason, uncommenting the last line is causing a segmentation fault. I am at a loss as to why this is happening, as it's just creating a new string.
The code is:

```
char str[] = "()";
if (isBalanced(str))
    printf("%s is balanced\n", str);
else printf("%s is not balanced\n", str);
char str1[] = "((1()";
if (isBalanced(str1))
    printf("%s is balanced\n", str1);
else printf("%s is not balanced\n", str1);
//char str2[] = "((1){()})";
```

There are no errors and the program runs as expected, but as soon as I uncomment the final line, a segmentation fault occurs before any of the print statements even print.

I have found that changing str2[] to hi[] fixes the issues, but why is that? stdio.h doesn't define any macros that interfere here and str2 is not a keyword in C. Please let me know if I'm overlooking something stupid.

Here's the complete program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int isBalanced(char *str) {
    int x = 0;
    int length;
    while (str[x++] != '\0') length++;
    char open[50];
    unsigned int numOpen = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        if (str[x] == '{')
            open[numOpen++] = str[x];
        if (str[x] == '(')
            open[numOpen++] = str[x];
        if (str[x] == '[')
            open[numOpen++] = str[x];
        if (str[x] == '}') {
            if (open[numOpen-1] != '{')
                return 0;
            else numOpen--;
        } 
        if (str[x] == ')') {
            if (open[numOpen-1] != '(')
                return 0;
            else numOpen--; 
        }
        if (str[x] == ']') {
            if (open[numOpen-1] != '[')
                return 0;
            else numOpen--; 
        }
    }
    return numOpen == 0;
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "()";
    if (isBalanced(str))
        printf("%s is balanced\n", str);
    else printf("%s is not balanced\n", str);
    char str1[] = "((1()";
    if (isBalanced(str1))
        printf("%s is balanced\n", str1);
    else printf("%s is not balanced\n", str1);
    char str2[] = "((1){()})";
    //if (isBalanced(str1))
    //  printf("%s is balanced\n", string);
    //else printf("%s is not balanced\n", string);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compile with warnings and optimizations on, and you will get a warning about `length` being uninitialized.  By the way, another illustration of the fact that when people try to post only the part of the code that contains the bug, they are usually wrong.

Comment: That seemed to fix it, but I still don't understand why any other name for str2[] doesn't cause this issue.

Comment: @Meegul because it's undefined behaviour. It doesn't fix it. Reboot your computer and maybe this time it "works" with `str2` and crashes with `hi`.

Comment: Modern compilers will give a warning about use of uninitialized variable - consider updating your compiler or turning up the warning level

Comment: @M.M `clang` (3.5.0) flagged this with just `-Wall` but `gcc` (5.3.1) needed `-Wall` _and_ [minimally] `-O1`

Comment: Modern, and old, debuggers will very likely show up an uninitialized variable.  Certainly, if causing a problem like an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: ' Please let me know if I'm overlooking something stupid.' - no, but you are overlooking something vary useful - your debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please let me know if I'm overlooking something stupid.

Yes, you are. You are using an uninitialized variable. That leads to undefined behavior. Change

```
int length;
```

to

```
int length = 0;
```

in `isBalanced`.